# Multiple Users Gmail Delegation

Tags: gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-workspace, delegation

When I do Gmail deletion I can select only one user at once. When there are a lot of users, It's very difficult to delegate them all. Is there any solution that can help to delegate multiple users at the same time?

Comment: Hi there @DilanaWeerasingha! You could perform a [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) to a [service account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726?hl=en). That account would have delegation privileges over every account in your organisation. I could help you with this approach, but would it be a valid one for your scenario?

Comment: if you can help. I would be really thankfull

Comment: Have you checked the example on [Preparing to make an authorized API call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests). There is shown how the delegation works and how you have to use one user. You could create a dictionary as mentioned below and setup the credentials and delegation for each user once and then use the one you need each time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way authorization works each time you authorize the application it is authorized to access a single users data.

This works exactly the same with delegation. You are delegating permissions to that single user.  There is now ay to delegate permissions to more the one user in the same authorization object.

Create yourself a dictionary or something with the authorization objects for each user.